# How to remove redundant column in tableviewer?

Tags: java, swt, tableviewer

I created tableviewer .

The columns are created dynamically.

The problem that I always have another column in the table.

I checked the names of the columns and I didn't get any empty column.

Maybe it could be a configuration of the tableviewer .

Do you have any idea why I always have another column ?

//The gridViewer Class

```
     public class MyGridViewer extends TableViewer {
     public MyGridViewer (Composite parent) {
    super(parent, SWT.MULTI | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.FULL_SELECTION | SWT.BORDER);

    final Table table = this.getTable();
    table.setHeaderVisible(true);
    table.setLinesVisible(true);

    this.setContentProvider(new MyModelProvider());

        }
      }


     @Override
    protected void inputChanged(Object input, Object oldInput) {

    removeColumn();



        tableCol = new TableViewerColumn(this, SWT.NONE);
        column = tableCol.getColumn();
        column.setText(dataColumnHeader.getName());
        column.setWidth(100);
        column.setResizable(true);
        column.setMoveable(true);
        tableCol.setLabelProvider(new ColumnLabelProvider() {
            @Override
            public String getText(Object element) {
                DataRow r = (DataRow) element;
                DataCell c = r.getDataCellByName(dataColumnHeader.getName());
                if (c != null && c.getValue() != null) {
                    return c.getValue().toString();
                }
                return null;
            }
             @Override
             public Image getImage(Object element) {
                   //Add my imgae
             }
        });



     editingSupport = new StringCellEditingSupport(this, dataColumnHeader);
     tableCol.setEditingSupport(editingSupport);
        super.inputChanged(input, oldInput);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what "redundant" column you're reffering to, but maybe you haven't disposed it properly (if you're saying they are created dynamically).

If I were you, I would add them differently.

```
private void createColumns()
{
    // First, dipose any previously created columns
    for (TableColumn column : table.getColumns())
         column.dispose();

    // Then recreate them
    for (MyColumnPO col : getColumns())
    {
         TableColumn newCol = new TableColumn(table, SWT.NONE); 
         newCol.setText( col.text );
         newCol.setWidth( col.width );
    }
}
```

`MyColumnPO` would be a POJO which stands for "My Column Presentation Object". This contains info about your columns (text, width, tooltip).

Now, in the `getColumns()` method, you add/create/delete/update desired columns, instantiating `MyColumnPO` objects, and adding them to a `List` which you will return.

Each time you need to re-create the columns dynamically, you call `createColumns()`.

Comment: I mean that I have another column even in the first time

Comment: so it is not related to the dispose.